# having weird problem with fetching data from api in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, async-await, fetch-api

i have a function that fetch data from api with 3 object and when i fetch them i get the data 3 times

can help me to understand the problem?

this is the api function.

```
export async function fetchMovies() {
    const response = await fetch(`${firebaseApi}/Movies.json`);
    const data = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(data.message || "Error");
    }

    const fetchedMovies = []

    for (const key in data) {
        const moviesObj = {
            id: key,
            ...data[key]
        }

        fetchedMovies.push(moviesObj);
    }
    return fetchedMovies;
}
```

i have added an images of the console.log and the api data from the server.

[this image show the console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VId2P.png)

[this image show the data i have on my api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWZZo.png)

Comment: Could you share the code where this function is called from?

Answer (score 0):

I think fetchMovies() is called everytime when component renders. Use effect with empty array so that your fetch movie function is called only once.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
useEffect(() => {
        
    fetchMovies();
    
}, [])
```